# Fail SonarQube quality gate if no tests were run

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I'm running my builds on Jenkins with both SonarQube scanner and plugin for Maven builds. How to fail Quality Gate if no tests were run during that build ?

Answer (score 1):

You have two metrics you can use here: Unit Tests, and Unit Test Duration. This assumes that you're feeding in a test execution report which you can have created automatically when tests run. When they don't, 0's should be automatically filled for those metrics.

Comment: But is it possible to generate a test execution report if no tests are run (with Gradle or Maven) ? Or do I need to provide a "custom made" report to get this.

Comment: @minas I've expanded my answer. See if it helps.